# use regex to "insert text not present" in other text

Tags: regex

I want to learn more about the structure and use of regex paths. My question is, using regex commands, can you enter non present text in another?

I explain, let's say, I have some text and I want to "add text" using a regex commands:

Some text : `these house is red`

Final text: `these house is red and blue`

I know the replace function is the solution

```
search: (.*)
replace: $1 and blue
```

but is there any way to enter that text using the regex command instead of using the replace function?

```
search: (.*)($1 and blue)
replace: $1$2
```

Comment: Regular Expressions are no commands. They don't manipulate texts in any way. Regular Expressions define textual patterns that are used to see if a piece of text matches the pattern. `.*` simply matches everything (except line break in some RegEx engines).

Comment: What is the tool you are using? Different tools, languages implement different version of RegEx. Like @mumpitz said, it is not the RegEx itself, it is the tool/language you are using. And welcome to SO :)

Comment: **close** unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which language you are using, but this answer applies to Python. Since you are only replacing text at the end of line, this should suffice (all you should need to do is modify the regex formula):

```
import re

s = 'these house is red'

s_new = re.sub(r'$', ' and blue', s)

print(s_new)
```

OUTPUT:

```
these house is red and blue
```

Note that the regex used here simply matches the end of the line (or string in this case):

```
r'$'
```

Comment: well, I use regex in a game called "Starmade", and the regex is used to manipulate text present in one of its components (Display block), is fun but complicated to implement.

Regex must be ejecuted usign this pattern:

[REPLACEALL] ... regex ... [WITH] ...

A simple animation to do is this:


https://i.imgur.com/Xhl0AMc.gif
https://regex101.com/r/uwzyCt/2
https://starmadedock.net/threads/starmade-maniac-logic.23946/page-7#post-346416

Comment: Apologies, but I am not familiar at all with Starmade and the links you provided did not clarify much for me. If you can provide more test cases, I would be more than happy to modify the regex I provided above to accommodate.

Comment: My intention is to be able to add text, using regex, which is not present in the text to implement, is there some way?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, this would be best achieved using regex to identify the pattern and then explicitly identify the text that you aim to insert as I have done above. The root of your question (I think) is how to identify this pattern(s), so providing more test cases would help me to better answer your question.